# Concurrent HashMap thread safety and happens-before relationship

Tags: java, synchronized, java.util.concurrent, concurrenthashmap

Sourcing javadoc for `ConcurrentHashMap`, I read the below statement that is bothering me about thread safety of the said collection.

From : [Class ConcurrentHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html)

> Retrieval operations (including get) generally do not block, so may overlap with update operations (including `put` and `remove`). Retrievals reflect the results of the most recently completed update operations holding upon their onset. For aggregate operations such as `putAll` and `clear`, concurrent retrievals may reflect insertion or removal of only some entries.

I find this paragraph self-contradictory. To be precise, statement 2 says retreivals reflect most recently completed operation , while statement 3 almost says that such a behaviour is not guaranteed for aggregate functions .

Does this mean aggregate operations like `putAll` and `clear` are still a risky bet ?

Comment: `ConcurrentHashMap` is one of the (mostly) non-blocking collection types. It locks only part of the map when updating its content by keeping several distinct locks. This does not give guarantees about synchronization after specific methods. It guarantees that you will not overwrite data or corrupt your collection. If you require a collection which will always provide you with the latest view of its data, switch to a `Collections.synchronizedMap` which locks every operation in a synchronized block. This has other implications, such as lock contention when lots of threads update or query the map

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does this mean aggregate operations like putAll and clear are still a risky bet ?

Their promise that "retrieval operations...do not block" puts some major restrictions on what else they can promise. For example, a `map.get(k)` call must *immediately* return either `null` or some `v` that was earlier `put(k,v)` with the same `k`. The `get(k)` call can't wait for some other thread to complete a `map.putAll(someEnormousOtherMap)` call. They *promised* that it would not block!

Basically they can't keep that promise, unless the only operations that appear to be atomic are the insertions/removals/replacements of *individual* key/value pairs. The only way that aggragate operations can be implemented without breaking the non-blocking-get() promise is to implement them as non-atomic sequences of calls to the atomic primitives that  operate on one key/value pair at a time.